# Localization and HTML5

Tags: html, localization

In HTML5 you can create a date selector as follows:

```
<input type="date" />
```

The browser will format the date presumably according to the browser's default language setting. Is it possible to set the language to use for the date selector or possibly for the entire page whereby all language dependent elements automatically use this language?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - according [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html), **nope**.

The value of the `input` is a **valid full-date as defined** in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) (which on other hand is based on Internet protocols that is a profile of the ISO 8601 standard for representation of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar), with the additional qualification that the year component is four or more digits representing a number greater than 0.

Example: `1999-12-19`

But, keep in mind, that this is **in-progress** standard development, so maybe in future versions localization will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The internal data format, as stored in the DOM and as sent as part of form data, is fixed for elements like [`<input type=date>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#date-state-%28type=date%29). The format is internationalized, “neutral”, and not really meant to be written and read by human beings. Some cultures and some people actually use date notations like the 2014-06-12, but this should be regarded as incidental. It is very unlikely that this will change, since this is the way software generally works this way.

The visible (or audible) presentation may vary. HTML5 drafts do not specify the details. They just refer to possible localization, which may take place according to the user interface language of the browser, or the declared language of the page content, or something else. In practice, browsers that implement these elements do so according to the browser language, so that if you create a page in English, someone using a Russian-language browser may see the date input widget with month names in Russian etc. It is debatable whether this is useful.

This means that you cannot control whether and how `<input type=date>` will be localized. For widget that will be localized in a controlled manner, you would need to use JavaScript code instead.

The same applies to other elements that may have a language-dependent implementation